# Display just child pages of a certain page in search results

Tags: search

StackExchangers!

I have searched the internet left right and center and still cannot find a way to alter the search results that are displayed. Basically I would like no posts and only child pages of this parent page to be displayed in the search results of my WP Site:

http://universitycompare.com/university-guide/

Otherwise, if none of these pages are displayed it would display null results.

Any help/direction is appreciated, I did try and gather as much information from here, forums and asking webdev friends - But I am completely stuck so I have resorted to asking StackExchange.

Hopefully this isn't too broad and you understand what I have been trying to figure out for days, otherwise if not, please ask for what you need and I can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following approach.

Get the page using `get_page_by_path()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path

```
$page = get_page_by_path( 'university-guide' );

$search_query['post_type'] = 'page';
$search_query['post_parent'] = $page->ID;
```

The following snippet was taken from Codex page: Creating a search form
http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

```
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
```

Search results are obtained using WP_Query instance.

You can use WP_Query codex page to learn more about available options.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query